# HTML submit form does not work as expected

Tags: web-services, web, web-applications, web-crawler

I have recently started practicing Html. I am working on simple submit form without any kind of data.
Here is my index.html code

```
    <html> 
    <body>
     <form action="/a.html"> <center><h1>Vignesh</h1> > </center> <BR><br> <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"> 
    </form> >
     </body> 
    </html>

Here is my a.html code...

    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>
    <b>SUBMITTED<b>
    </h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

when I press SUBMIT it shows "File a.html? not found" I don't know it adds '?' in end. If remove ? manually from link it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action="/a.html" method="POST">
         <center>
            <h1>Vignesh</h1>
            > 
         </center>
         <BR><br> <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"> 
      </form>
      >
   </body>
</html>
```

Add an attribute `method="POST"` will fix your question mark issue.